# pyspark 2.2.0 concept behind raw predictions field of logistic regression model

Tags: machine-learning, pyspark, logistic-regression, apache-spark-ml

I was trying to understand the concept of the output generated from logistic regression model in Pyspark.

Could anyone please explain the concept behind the `rawPrediction` field calculation generated from a logistic regression model?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In older versions of the Spark [javadocs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/ml/classification/ClassificationModel.html#predictRaw(FeaturesType)) (e.g. 1.5.x), there used to be the following explanation:

> The meaning of a "raw" prediction may vary between algorithms, but it intuitively gives a measure of confidence in each possible label (where larger = more confident).

It is not there in the later versions, but you can still find it in the Scala [source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/classification/Classifier.scala#L205).

Anyway, and any unfortunate wording aside, the `rawPrecictions` in Spark ML, for the logistic regression case, is what the rest of the world call [*logits*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit), i.e. the raw output of a logistic regression classifier, which is subsequently transformed into a probability score using the [logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) `exp(x)/(1+exp(x))`.

Here is an example with toy data:

```python
spark.version
# u'2.2.0'

from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.sql import Row
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
     (0.0, Vectors.dense(0.0, 1.0)),
     (1.0, Vectors.dense(1.0, 0.0))], 
     ["label", "features"])
df.show()
# +-----+---------+
# |label| features|
# +-----+---------+
# |  0.0|[0.0,1.0]|
# |  1.0|[1.0,0.0]|
# +-----+---------+

lr = LogisticRegression(maxIter=5, regParam=0.01, labelCol="label")
lr_model = lr.fit(df)

test = sc.parallelize([Row(features=Vectors.dense(0.2, 0.5)),
                       Row(features=Vectors.dense(0.5, 0.2))]).toDF()
lr_result = lr_model.transform(test)
lr_result.show(truncate=False)
```

Here is the result:

```python
+---------+----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+----------+ 
|features |                          rawPrediction |                            probability |prediction|
+---------+----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+----------+ 
|[0.2,0.5]|[0.9894187891647654,-0.9894187891647654]|[0.7289731070426124,0.27102689295738763]|      0.0 |
|[0.5,0.2]|[-0.9894187891647683,0.9894187891647683]|[0.2710268929573871,0.728973107042613]  |      1.0 | 
+---------+----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+----------+
```

Let's now confirm that the logistic function of `rawPrediction` gives the `probability` column:

```python
import numpy as np

x1 = np.array([0.9894187891647654,-0.9894187891647654])
np.exp(x1)/(1+np.exp(x1))
# array([ 0.72897311, 0.27102689])

x2 = np.array([-0.9894187891647683,0.9894187891647683])
np.exp(x2)/(1+np.exp(x2))
# array([ 0.27102689, 0.72897311])
```

i.e. this is the case indeed

---

So, to summarize regarding all three (3) output columns:

- `rawPrediction` is the raw output of the logistic regression classifier (array with length equal to the number of classes)
- `probability` is the result of applying the logistic function to `rawPrediction` (array of length equal to that of `rawPrediction`)
- `prediction` is the argument where the array `probability` takes its maximum value, and it gives the most probable label (single number)